# Solving a derivative with several variables.

Tags: calculus

So I get the general sense of all of this and calculated all of the partial derivatives but I am unsure what exactly it is asking me for. Any advice or explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Let $F: R^{3} \to R^{2}$ be defined by $F(x,y,z) = (y(z+6)^{1/3}, z\sin(3x-y))$. Find $DF(1,3,2)$. Using the first part approximate $F(.99, 3.01, 2.02)$ by $F(1,3,2)$.

Comment: I believe you dropped a part of the question. And $DF$ is not a common notation. Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

Calculating the partial derivatives basically tells you the slope of the function in the $x,y,z$ direction. When you calculate $\partial F(1,3,2)$ with respect to $x,y$ and $z$, you get the slope values at the point (1,3,2). What it is asking you is to approximate a point close to the point whose slope you calculated. To do this is

$$ F(0.99, 3.01, 2.02) \approx F(1,3,2) - .01F_x(1,3,2) + .01F_y(1,3,2) + .02F_z(1,3,2) $$

where $F_x, F_y, F_z$ are the partial derivatives of $F$. Another way to write this is

$$ F(a + \alpha, b + \beta, c + \gamma) \approx F(a,b,c) + (\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \cdot\nabla F(a,b,c) $$

where $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ are small perturbations to the point $(a,b,c)$ and $\nabla$ is the gradient.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in addition could you elaborate on how you solved for DF(1,3,2)?

Comment: @Andrew do you know how to take partial derivatives?

Comment: Indeed I do. I actually have them all listed out. What I do not know how to do is apply them to get DF(1,3,2).

Comment: @Andrew I assume when you say DF(1,3,2) you mean $\nabla F = (F_x, F_y, F_z)$. If that is the case, just plug in the values after taking the partial derivatives.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe I have it now. Is there a way to private message so I can tell you my answer without posting it here?

Comment: @Andrew what is wrong with posting the answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the definition of $DF$: it’s the best *linear* approximation to the change in $F$ at a point. Symbolically, $$F(\mathbf x+\Delta\mathbf x)=F(\mathbf x)+DF(\mathbf x)\Delta\mathbf x+o(\Delta\mathbf x).$$ That is, for a small displacement $\Delta\mathbf x$ from $\mathbf x$, the value of $F(\mathbf x+\Delta\mathbf x)$ is approximately $F(\mathbf x)+DF(\mathbf x)\Delta\mathbf x$.

In your problem, $\mathbf x=(1,3,2)^T$ and $\Delta\mathbf x=(0.99,3.01,2.02)^T-(1,3,2)^T=(-0.01,0.01,0.02)^T$. $DF$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$: the $2\times 3$ matrix of the partial derivatives at $\mathbf x$, which you’ve already computed. The rest is a matter of plugging in these values.